# CefSharp showes no popup for "allow website to open programm" when clicking `mailto:` link

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am hosting a webside inside `CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser`

**On Internet Explorer:**

When clicking a mailto-link `"mailto:?subject=....&body=...."` Internet Explorer shows a popup asking

> Allow website to open a program (Outlook) for "mailto:?subject=....&body=...."

[image: Popup when clicking mailto-links]

**On ChromiumWebBrowser:**
The page navigates away from the page with the link and and no popup is shown.

What part of CefSharp do I have to supply to allow such popups to happen?

Edit:

**On Chrome**: Email opens in Outlook

Comment: Looks like you need to inspect each navigation event with a custom `IRequestHandler` and deal with non-http(s) links yourself: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/735

Comment: @JamesThorpe looks promising, want to make it an answer?

Comment: Not really in a position to at the moment - I'd want to build an actual one to make sure it works. If you get it working, feel free to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [James Thorpe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/791010/james-thorpe) comment I used   [CefSharp.Example/RequestHandler.cs](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/RequestHandler.cs) as base for a RequestHandler - changing

```
bool IRequestHandler.OnBeforeBrowse (IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser,
    IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isRedirect)
{
    if (request.Url.StartsWith ("mailto:"))
    {
        // use system defined handler for mailto:/ ...
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (request.Url); 

        // skip browse
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


bool IRequestHandler.OnProtocolExecution (IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, 
    string url) => false;
```

In my case I want to prevent browsing if a mailto: is incoming.
I do use custom protocol handlers so I allow them all - for now.

I set an instance of this RequestHandler (ChromiumWebBrowser-Instance).RequestHandler and now it works.

Email opens, site stays where it is. No side effects - yet.